# how to search for a group name within the active directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hi I would like to find out where my AD group called BIDEV is located within my AD, as you can see on the pictures below.

It exists, but where is it?

Also, any example of how I could do this using Powershell?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [Get-ADGroup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#------------------------------
# first part search for a user
#------------------------------

Clear-Host 

$SearchFor = "mmartin"

import-module activedirectory 
Write-Host "Searching..." 
$all_users_list=Get-ADUser -filter * -properties SamAccountName,sn,GivenName,mail,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Country,DistinguishedName,CanonicalName |  
select-object SamAccountName,sn,GivenName,mail,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Country,DistinguishedName,CanonicalName -ErrorAction silentlycontinue 

foreach($u in $all_users_list)
{
    if($u.SamAccountName -like "*$SearchFor*")
    {
    $Output = $u.SamAccountName + " - " + $u.DistinguishedName
    Write-Host $Output 
    }
}

Write-Host "Done" 
#that will work
#just put what you want at the top in "SearchFor"
#mmartin my powershell guru - 16-july-2015


#------------------------------
# second part search for a group
#------------------------------


 Clear-Host 

$SearchFor = "BIDEV"

import-module activedirectory 
Write-Host "Searching..." 
$all_group_list=Get-ADGroup -filter * -properties * |  
select-object * -ErrorAction silentlycontinue 

foreach($u in $all_group_list)
{
    if($u.SamAccountName -like "*$SearchFor*")
    {
    $Output = $u.SamAccountName + " - " + $u.DistinguishedName
    Write-Host $Output 
    }
}

Write-Host "Done"
```

[image]

Comment: first part of the script I look for the user mmartin

Comment: second part of the script I look for AD groups that the name contain BIDEV. I thought I had only one, I added the picture with the results